# JSF2 ajax tag throws unknown javascript error in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2, openfaces

Having this lines of code:

```
<h:commandLink value="Reset Filter" styleClass="button">
  <f:ajax event="click" render="filterWindowDiv tableX" listener="#{beanX.reset}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

and as well as with:

```
<h:commandLink value="Reset Filter" styleClass="button">
  <f:ajax event="click" render="@all" listener="#{beanX.reset}" />
</h:commandLink>
```

an unknown error will be thrown in Internet Explorer 8:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method         pageX.jsf, line1 character 7
```

The `h:commandLink` is within a `o:window` (OpenFaces 3).

However, I do get the same error if I am using the same lines of code for example for a Delete button which shows after invoking a bean method a `o:popupLayer`.

Any ideas? Thank you in advance!

---

I've had JavaScript code within my div which must be rendered adhoc while re-render a part of the page. However, it seems IE cannot handle that issue while FF don't mind. I think to remember I've read something something about this. Anyway, since I've removed the JavaScript error is gone.

But how to invoke my JavaScript code **after rendering**? I've solved it like this example:

```
<h:commandLink value="Reset Filter" styleClass="button">
  <f:ajax event="click" render="@all" listener="#{beanX.reset}" 
          onevent="callback" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Callback method:

```
function callback(data) {
  data.status == "success") {
    // your JavaScript code
  }
}
```

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: IE8 does not see <h: or <f: unless your server does not render them. Load the url into firefox as `view-source:http://.....` and see if that makes things clearer

Comment: Checked in a browser that gives more error information yet? Like FireFox + FireBug or Chrome. Or is it just IE only?

Comment: Not surprising the error just occurs in Internet Explorer 8, it's not reproducable in FF.

Comment: How about when you create a pure JSF page without OpenFaces? I cannot reproduce your problem with Mojarra 2.1.1 on Tomcat 7.0.12.

Comment: I think it has its cause within the OpenFaces components, if you cannot reproduce it with a pure JSF page. I've to postpone the analysis currently because of other more important tasks. :-/ Thank you anyway!

Comment: It seems to be a IE "bug" or behaviour that JavaScript code cannot be rendered adhoc.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here lies with click event of `<h:commandLink>`

Don't know the possible cause, but using `mousedown` will hopefully solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately using onmousedown event in `<f:ajax event="mousedown" render="@all" listener="#{beanX.reset}" />` within the `h:commandLink` the tag didn't solve the problem.

Comment: It is interesting... it looks likes with an `onmouseup' event it is working BUT event will be thrown with a right mouse click as well. This behaviour is not wanted and in that case the JS error happens again.

Comment: @Zubi - Then detect right click event and ignore the code if so.. Check [Which mouse button has been clicked](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html)

Comment: Yes, that's a way to do it. However, I'm invoking a method of a bean. I might be able to first catch the JS and then invoking the method... Thank you.